# Problema con un "fi" en mi código de BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell

tengo problema con el "fi" que me marca al final la consola.
Adjunto mensaje y enlace del código.

Código:

```
# !/bin/bash
# Proyecto Final Laboratorio - Buscador de ficheros
# Sergio Esteban Tarrero
# Proyecto ejecutado en CentOS 7 con interfaz gráfica

# Variables
DIRECTORIO=$1
OPCION=$2
OPCIONEXTRA=$3
ACCION=$4

# Usamos una flag para que nos haga un \n  entre los archivos que se sacan por pantalla
let FLAG=0

#función principal

# MENÚ
function menu ()
{
    echo -e "Forma de usar el programa: "
    echo -e " <directorio> <opción de búsqueda> <opción extra> <acción> \n"
    echo -e "Ejemplo: /home/sergio/downloads/pruebas -t -d -print"
    echo -e "IMPORTANTE: Todos los comandos introducidos deben estar escritos en minúsculas"
}

# LISTAR --> pone en una lista los ficheros
function listar ()
{
    if [[ ${FLAG} = 1 ]]
    then
        lista+=(\n)
    fi
        lista+=${FICHERO}
}

# Primera comprobación para ver si existe el directorio introducido
if [[ ! -r ${DIRECTORIO} ]]
then

    echo -e "ERROR: El directorio introducido no existe, pruebe otro \n"
    menu # vuelve al menú principal

else

    # Switch Case de posibles elecciones de OPCIÓN

    case "${OPCION}" in

     "-t") # Caso buscar por TIPO DE ARCHIVO

        case "${OPCIONEXTRA}" in

            "-f") # Mira solo los ficheros normales, (Ej: .txt y fotos)
                for fichero in "${DIRECTORIO}"/*;
                do
                    if [[ -r "${FICHERO}" && -f "${FICHERO}" ]]
                    then
                        listar
                    fi
                    done
                ;;

            "-d") # Mira solo los directorios
                for fichero in "${DIRECTORIO}"/*;
                do
                    if [[ -r "${FICHERO}" && -d "${FICHERO}" ]]
                    then
                        listar
                    fi
                    done
                ;;

            "-") # Muestra todo
                for fichero in "${DIRECTORIO}"/*;
                do
                  listar
                done
                ;;

            *) # Caso de error
               echo -e "ERROR: Solo se pueden introducir los comandos -f, -d y -"
               menu
               ;;
        esac
        ;;

     "-n") # Caso buscar por NOMBRE DE ARCHIVO
        for fichero in "${DIRECTORIO}"/*;
        do
          if [[ "${FICHERO}" == *"${OPCIONEXTRA}"* ]]
          then
            listar
          fi
        done
        ;;

     "-p") # Caso buscar por PERMISOS DE ARCHIVO

        case "${OPCIONEXTRA}" in

            "-x") # Esribe que lea
                for fichero in "${DIRECTORIO}"/*;
                do
                   if [[ -x "${FICHERO}" && -f "${FICHERO}" ]] || [[ -x "${FICHERO}" && -d "${FICHERO}" ]]
                then
                    listar
                fi
                done
                ;;

            "-r") # Poder leerlo
                for fichero in "${DIRECTORIO}"/*;
                do
                   if [[ -r "${FICHERO}" && -f "${FICHERO}" ]] || [[ -r "${FICHERO}" && -d "${FICHERO}" ]]
                then
                    listar
                fi
                done
                ;;

            "-w") # Se puede escribir
                for fichero in "${DIRECTORIO}"/*;
                do
                   if [[ -w "${FICHERO}" && -f "${FICHERO}" ]] || [[ -w "${FICHERO}" && -d "${FICHERO}" ]]
                then
                    listar
                fi
                done
                ;;

            *) # Demás opciones
                echo -e "ERROR: Solo se pueden introducir los comandos -t, -n y -w"
                ;;

     "-c") # Caso buscar por TODO, hay que comprobarlo manualmente
        for fichero in "${DIRECTORIO}"/*;
        do
          if [[ -r "${FICHERO}" && -f "${FICHERO}" && -s "${FICHERO}" ]]
        then
            grep -c "${OPCIONEXTRA}" "${FICHERO}" &>/dev/null

            if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
            then
                listar
            fi
          fi
        done
        ;;

     *) # Todo lo demás
        echo -e "ERROR: Solo se pueden introducir los comandos -x, -r, -p y -c"
        ;;

    esac

 case "${ACCION}" in

    "-print" | "") # Imprimir la búsqueda realizada

      shift # Shift mueve el nº de los argumentos
      echo -e "${lista[@]}"
      ;;

    "-exec") # Ejecutar el fichero después de buscarlo

      while [[ $# -gt 4 ]]
      do
        args+=${5}
        shift # Shift mueve el nº de los argumentos
      done

      echo -e "NO FUNCIONA"
      ;;

    *) # Todas las demás opciones
      echo -e "ERROR:ERROR: Solo se pueden introducir los comandos -print o -exec \n"
      ;;

 esac

fi
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Te falta cerrar el `case` que hay dentro de la opción `-p`:

```
.
.
.
    *) # Demás opciones
        echo -e "ERROR: Solo se pueden introducir los comandos -t, -n y -w"
        ;;
    esac
    ;;

 "-c") # Caso buscar por TODO, hay que comprobarlo manualmente
.
.
.
```